# locale for Chinese Language as per I18n standards

Tags: ruby-on-rails, locale, rails-i18n

I would like to know the standard code for `Chinese language` in the available locales of `I18n` standards. For example `:en` for English. Also tell me how to name the `yml` file for chinese langauge (en.yml for English).

adding `zh.yml` into `/config/locales/` and specifying code for chinese as `:zh` is not working.

I18n.available_locales in rails console gives only the below lines.

```
irb(main):022:0> I18n.available_locales
=> [:ar, :en, :de]
```

I couldn't see :zh there inside. How we can include chinese translation code inside this?

Thanks :)-

Comment: Are you talking about this ? https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/zh-CN.yml

Comment: yes, exactly. but its not working

Comment: Copy this file in your config/locales directory with the name zh.yml and in your application.rb change your default locale to :zh

Comment: @Intrepidd: That is not working friend.

Answer (score 6):

if you are looking for the simplified chinese, it is `zh-CN`. For the traditional `zh-TW`.

Comment: Still adding this file `zh-TW.yml` -- my app can't seem to find it.

Comment: I don't get it, it says right in the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) "including only the locale ("language") part, like :en, :pl, not the region part, like :en-US or :en-GB" but `:zh` doesn't seem to work, only `'zh-CN'`?